# is my branch tracking to master?

Tags: git, branch

I did this:

```
git branch --track stats_page
```

to create a separate branch to try something out. But now everytime I push or pull I see:

```
$ git pull
From .
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

and

```
$ git push
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To .
   ff0caf5..e360168  stats_page -> master
```

I'm far from a git master so I might be miss understanding what's happening - but is my stats_page branch tracking to master?

I may have created the branch wrong - if so - can I fix it so that from now on it pushes and pulls to the remote stats_page branch?  How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer: The easiest way to fix this is in [Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

## What's really going on here

I've always found descriptions of git's "tracking branches" confusing myself.  They sound, to me at least, like they do a lot more than they really do.

The trick, I think, is to realize that git doesn't ever actually "track" a remote repository at all.  (It does *fetch* from a remote repo.)  Instead, a "tracking branch" tracks a branch *in your own repo*.  To "track a remote branch", you create a branch whose name says that it was originally copied from some other repo.  (Under the covers, this means any branch stored under `refs/remotes/`, more or less.)  The most common "other repo" is the one named `origin`, which is the one that an initial `git clone` sets up for you.  As it says in the git-clone manual page:

> This default configuration is achieved by creating references to the remote branch heads under `refs/remotes/origin` and by initializing `remote.origin.url` and `remote.origin.fetch` configuration variables.

When you use `git branch --track` to create a branch, it makes the new branch "track" the "start point" that you give it.  (And, "track" mainly means "associate for various push/pull/fetch actions, and tell me more when I run `git status`.)  So, assuming the repo you cloned-from already has a `stats_page` branch, you probably *meant* to do this:

```
git branch --track stats_page origin/stats_page
```

which tells git "make new branch named `stats_page` that tracks what I have in `refs/remotes/origin/stats_page`" (you normally leave off the `refs/heads` and `refs/remotes` parts, and git figures them out).  You don't even need the `--track` here, as the `origin/` part on the right turns that on for you.

Once you do all that, in git's terminology, you have a "local" branch (`refs/heads/stats_page`) that tracks a "remote" branch (`refs/remotes/origin/stats_page`).  To actually update the "remote" branch you use `git fetch`, or more explicitly, `git fetch origin`, which goes out to the URL associated with `origin` and collects any new stuff and then adds it to your repo.  Hence, despite calling this "remote", it's still remarkably local: it's right there on your own local disk.

(I have taken to calling git "the Borg of SCMs": "We are the git-Borg. We will add your commit distinctiveness to our own."  Most of what you do just adds new stuff to your own repo-Borg-collective.)

Once you've used `git fetch` to update your local copy of the "remote" branch (`origin/stats_page`), you can do a `git merge` to get it merged in (to `stats_page`, the name without the `origin/` part).  And, a `git pull` just runs those two in one easy step—which hides the fact that it's the `fetch` that actually gets new stuff from the "remote"

Now, the problem you have is that when you ran:

```
git branch --track stats_page
```

you were on your `master` branch, so you created a new "local" branch named `stats_page` that tracks your `master`, instead of tracking `origin/stats_page`.  Hence, `git pull` and `git push` just pull and push on your local branch named `master`.  (Note: If you actually run `git fetch`, that still fetches into `remotes/origin/*`, so it still updates `origin/stats_page`, even though the one "local" branch is mistakenly tracking another "local" branch.)

One last note: usually when you make a "local" branch that tracks a remote branch of the same name, you also want to do a `git checkout` immediately.  You can just `git checkout -b stats_page origin/stats_page` to get all three steps done at once.  (If your version of git is old, it may not automatically track when you name `origin/stats_page` on the right; but if so you probably should just update your version of git.)

---

Footnote: Some people recommend against using `git pull` at all, and I sort of agree with them.  `git pull` really mixes two very different operations.  In particular `git pull remote_A remote_B` seems to surprise people when it does an octopus merge.  Using `git fetch` never seems to surprise people; and once they get used to, and familiar with, an explicit `git merge`, the logic behind fast-forward merges makes a lot more sense.  Still, `git pull` with no arguments is so convenient....

Answer (score 1):

open .git/config in a text editor, and look for something like:

```
 push = stats_page:master
```

You'll probably find something like that in the section for your remote (not your branch).

You can delete it. By default push and pull operations push/pull all matching names. The push option makes it so you can have a local branch push to a remote branch with a different name.

Look at the section for your branch too, you may need to adjust the "merge" option there.