# How to interpret git error during repo update?

Tags: git, github, command-line

I am trying to update my Github repo.

**OS/config**: Using OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) on MacBook Air

After doing these commands:

```
$ git init
$ git add
$ git commit -m "added new stuff"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

I got this error:

```
To https://github.com/user/repo.git>
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to
'https://github.com/user/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then I tried...

```
$ git pull --commit https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

And I got...

```
Merge https://github.com/user/repo
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

Question

What do these errors mean in English? And what should I do next?

Is there a way to just "dump" whatever is in queue (without trying to "pull" it) so I can just get on with the new commits? I am thoroughly confused about what to do next.

Comment: Will the person who downvoted this question please explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me suggest that you read [the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), because most of the documentation that comes with git is pretty bad, especially for newbies.  (It's improved from where it was 5+ years ago, but it still leaves much to be desired.)

That said, let me try a quick introduction to "what you need to know" here.

#### Introductory stuff

1. When working with other people (including github which counts as "other people" here), you're having your git call up their git over the internet-phone and exhcange work.  These other people are *peers*, i.e., they have the exact same ability to do new work that you do, at least in the general case (github won't itself do new work all on its own).  What this means is that during an exchange, you might have things "they" (whoever they are) don't but they might also have things you don't.
2. Git exchanges work with individual commits.<sup>1</sup>  Exactly *which* commits, and how, gets a bit more complicated, so let's hold off on that for a moment.
3. The opposite of `git push` is not `git pull`, it's actually `git fetch`.  I think the error message you get should not refer directly to `git pull`; we'll see more on this in a bit as well.
4. Git keeps track of commits internally by their "true name" SHA-1 IDs, which are the long 40-character-hex things you see in `git log` output, for instance.  Every commit has some set of "parent" commits, identified by SHA-1 IDs.  You could use SHA-1 IDs yourself, but they're extremely human-unfriendly, you'd never remember whether you should start with `f13c9ab` or `0e1d227` or whatever (and these are *abbreviated* IDs!).
5. So, git therefore provides you, the user, with branch names like `master`.  A branch name is simply a name that you tell git to use to keep track of the *newest* commit you've made on that branch.
6. The newest commit has, as its parent, the commit that "used to be newest", which has an even older "newest" as its parent, and so on.  (The way git achieves this is remarkably simple: when you make a new commit, its parent is "the current commit", and once the commit is safely stored in the repository, git replaces the ID stored in the branch with the ID of the new commit just made.)

Given the last three items, let's draw a commit graph fragment:

```
... <- 1f3a33c <- 98ab102   <-- branch
```

Here, the tip of the branch is commit `98ab102` and its parent is `1f3a33c`.  We can say that the name `branch` "points to" `98ab102`, which points to its parent, and so on.

When you make a new repository (`git init`, assuming this actually makes one<sup>2</sup>) it's entirely empty of commits, so the first commit has *no* parent.  It's the second and third and so on commits that point back to previous commits.

When you do a "merge", you tell git to take two (or more,<sup>3</sup> but let's just say two, for now) existing commits and make a new commit that has *both* of those as parents, by combining all the changes from some common point.  Merges are not that complicated, but they're something you should generally do after deliberately dividing up work into separate lines of development.

#### Now, back to fetch, push, and pull

You've created a new repository (`git init`), put in at least one commit (`git commit`), and added a "remote" (`git remote add origin ...`).  This last step says "I have a peer git I want to call `origin`, so remember the URL under that name."

Then, you asked your git to call up "origin" (`git push ... origin`) and give it your commits as found under your branch-name "master" (`git push ... master`).  Here's where it gets a little bit tricky.  When your git talks to his git, what name should *his* git use?  The short answer here is that *his* git will use the name `master` too.  This is changeable, but changing it is not what you want here.

(You also asked, via the `-u` flag, to have your git *record* this exchange in your git configuration.  We'll leave that aside for now.)

When your git called up his git, your git said "here, look at these shiny new commits" (and he did), and then your git said: "Why not add these new commits *exactly as they are* to your repository,<sup>4</sup> and make your `master` point to the tip-most of those commits?"  His answer was: "Well, I *could* do that, but then I'd lose some commits *I* have that *you* don't."  This is where you see the `rejected` message.

Maybe you want them to forget their stuff-so-far.  If so, you can ask for a "force push", where you have your git tell them to set their `master` even if that "loses" some commits.  It's still up to them whether to do this, but often it's not what you want.

Maybe you want to pick up what they have and add it to *your* collection, or pick up what they have and toss out your own work-so-far.  This is where you want `git fetch`.

What `git fetch` does, de-complicated as much as possible,<sup>5</sup> is call up the peer over the Internet-phone and find out what *they* have that *you* don't.  It brings over all these commits (remember, the exchanges go by commits) and adds them, Borg-like, to your repository.  Then—this is the crucial part—it changes *their* branch-names so that they won't interfere with *your* branch-names.

The names that `git fetch` uses to synchronize with your peers are called "remote-tracking branches" or sometimes "remote branches".  One odd thing about "remote branches" is that they're *not* actually on the remote!  They're kept in *your own* repository.  The reason is simple: they're a snapshot of what was on the remote, the last time your git talked to that remote.  After the two gits hang up the Internet-phone, the remote could get changed.  (How fast a remote *actually* changes depends, of course, on how busy that remote git is.)

The renaming-pattern here is simple: take the remote's branch name (like `master`) and add the name of the remote (`origin`) in front: your `origin/master` "tracks" `origin`'s `master`.  (There's a full-name form that you can use if you accidentally name one of your own purely-local, not-remote-tracking, branches `origin/oops` for instance, but your best bet is not to do that in the first place.)

#### Wait, where does `git pull` come in?

Note that so far, it's been all `git push` and `git fetch`.  But suppose you've done a `git fetch` and picked up their work?  Now you have a bit of a problem: you have *your* work, and you have *their* work, and these two have diverged.

If you both started from a common base, we can draw your commit graph like this:

```
... base <- yours   <-- HEAD -> master
         \
           theirs   <-- origin/master
```

I put in the `HEAD ->` this time to show which branch you're on (run `git status` and you should see "on branch master" in its output).

One easy way to tie these two divergent bits of work together is to use `git merge`.  If you want to do that, you simply run `git merge origin/master` (note the slash: you want your git to find *your* `origin/master`, which it picked up during `git fetch`, and merge that into your `master`, making a new commit on your `master`).  The result looks like this:

```
... base <- yours <- merge  <-- HEAD -> master
         \         /
           theirs      <-- origin/master
```

Another way to handle this—usually the better way, in fact—is to use `git rebase`, which I won't go into in detail here; there are plenty of over StackOverflow answers about using `rebase`.  If you do, though, you wind up with:

```
... base <- theirs <- yours   <-- HEAD -> master
                  \
                   .......... <-- origin/master
```

(Note that in all cases, `origin/master` still points to the tip-most "theirs" commit.)

The main point to keep in mind right now is that whatever you do, if you want to get their git to accept your commits without having to force-push, you need to make your work be an add-on to theirs, so that your new commits "point back to" theirs.  It doesn't matter to the `push` process whether your work has theirs as a "second parent" of a merge commit, or simply builds directly on their commit(s); it only needs to point to their commits, by their commit-IDs.  (But again, rebase is usually better than merge!)

#### So, `git pull` (finally!)...

What `git pull` does, simplified, is just run `git fetch` and then `git merge`.  In short, it's meant as a convenience script: you're always fetching and then merging, so we'll give you a script that fetches, then merges.

Of course, `git merge` is usually wrong.  It really should use `git rebase` by default.

You can *make* `git pull` use `git rebase`,<sup>6</sup> but I think it's wiser, at least (or especially?) for newbies, to use the two separate steps—in part because if something goes wrong, the way you *recover* from this is different for the two different actions.  To get out of a failing merge, you use `git merge --abort`.  To get out of a failing rebase, you use `git rebase --abort`.  (These used to be even more different, now it's just "abort whatever's failing", which is a big improvement.  But you need to know which to do, and that's an awful lot clearer if you started with `git merge` or `git rebase`.)

#### The bottom line

In the end, the action you need to take here depends on what you want to have happen, *and* what the remote will allow you to do.  If you want to drop *their* stuff, use `git push -f` (force), being aware that you're causing them (whoever they are) pain this way, and that they might forbid it entirely.  If you want to keep their stuff, use `git fetch` first, then keep their stuff however you prefer (merge, rebase, rework, whatever).

---

<sup>1</sup>Or with patches, which you can exchange with your peers by email.  It's also possible to "bundle" commits and transfer them by other methods.  But in this case we're doing commit-based exchanges over the Internet-phone.

<sup>2</sup>You can safely run `git init` in an existing repository.  It has a minor effect but for our purposes here it basically does nothing, hence the need to say "assuming it actually makes one".

<sup>3</sup>Git calls this an "octopus" merge, even if there are just 3 or 4 parents instead of 8.

<sup>4</sup>Git mostly only ever adds "more stuff".  I like to refer to this as the ["Git Borg"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9858953/1256452), where git adds your technological distinctiveness to its existing collection.

<sup>5</sup>A common theme in git is "That wasn't quite what you wanted?  OK, we'll keep the existing stuff but *make it more complicated* so you can do what *you* want too!"

<sup>6</sup>See footnote 5.

Answer (score 1):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015/1640892) suggests:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

But I haven't tried it yet, so I can't say for certain whether it solves the problem. But it is, at least, one direction to try.

Comment: Don't forget the warning:  **If you have any local changes, they will be lost.**

Answer (score 1):

GIT is telling you to fetch first. You can see in the log

```
$ git fetch -all
```

Probably somebody else has pushed to master already, and your commit is behind. Therefore you have to fetch, merge the change set, and then you'll be able to push again.

If it says there are changes in the remote make a Pull which will update your working directory.

```
$ git pull
```

Then you push your changes to the remote

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

I hope this will help you push your changes to the master